# mouse listener function stack

Tags: java, mouselistener

i have 2 different variable pencilTools and brushTools, when i declare brushTools then i declare pencilTools the brushTools should be null and the mousepressed on pencilTools should not active but in my case it still active even though the pencilTools is null. how to clear the pencilTools when i declare brushTools so it doesn't stack.

this is the  code :

```
if (e.getActionCommand()=="Brush"){
            pencilTools = null;
            brushTools = new BrushTools(mousePos,canvas,properties);
        }
else if (e.getActionCommand()=="Pencil"){
            brushTools = null;
            pencilTools = new PencilTools(mousePos,canvas,properties);
        }
```

```
PencilTools(JLabel mousePos,JPanel canvas,Properties properties){
        this.mousePos=mousePos;
        this.canvas=canvas;
        canvas.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        canvas.addMouseListener(this);
        this.properties=properties;
    }
@Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("pencil pressed");
        }
    }
```

```
BrushlTools(JLabel mousePos,JPanel canvas,Properties properties){
        this.mousePos=mousePos;
        this.canvas=canvas;
        canvas.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        canvas.addMouseListener(this);
        this.properties=properties;
    }
@Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("brush pressed");
        }
    }
```

when i click the pencil then brush, the output will be pencil pressed and brush pressed,
[here's the output with only 2 clicks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvqGk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to delete previous listener before register a new listener on canvas (JPanel).

```
MouseListener[] mouseListeners = canvas.getMoseListeners();
for (int i=0; ......) {
canvas.removeMouseListener (mouseListener[i]);
}

MouseMotionListener[] motionListeners = canvas.getMouseMotionListeners ();
for (int i=0; ....) {
canvas.removeMouseMotionListener (motionlisteners[i);
}
```